# Abstracting input fields in React to not repeat in every component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Our React application is quite big and one of the most often used component is the input field (we are using the one that's provided by the material UI library). These components look very similar, something like this:

```
<TextField
    id="fieldName"
    label="Field Name"
    name="fieldName"
    value={this.state.formData.fieldName}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
    helperText={this.HELPER_TEXTS.fieldName}
    error={this.state.isInError.fieldName}
/>
```

The `handleChange` function is also almost always the same basic one and this two things resulted in a lot of repetition and copy pasting previous components.

The frontend dev that worked here before me solved this repetition issue by creating a wrapper component but (imo) he went a bit too far with that idea and also included storing the field data an wrapping the `<form>` in a custom component. This resulted in a rigid system that was hard to extend or use for the few components which didn't fit for this "template".

I reverted his efforts and created a `generalProperties` function in every place we had input fields so it was easy to deviate from the norm in a case-by-case basis but still required less repetition. The function looks something like this:

```
getGeneralProps(field) {
    return {
        helperText: this.HELPER_TEXTS.field,
        error: this.isInErrorState(field),
        id: field,
        name: field,
        onChange: this.handleChange,
        value: this.state.formData[field],
    };
}
```

And a component using the function like this:

```
<TextField
    label='Field Name'
    {...this.getGeneralProps('fieldName')}
/>
```

But I still find myself copy-pasting this and the `handleChange` function over and over again so I thought that my approach could still be improved however I'm not sure about how good or bad a practice is to separate essential parts of a component like this.

### My questions are:

1. Is this a common problem? Does anyone figured out a general way to deal with this?
2. Was I right to replace the efforts of the previous dev with my solution?
3. Is my solution suboptimal? Does it have place for improvement?

Comment: This question should be posted in [Code Review | StackExchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Good question nevertheless. +1

Comment: I'm more interested in the "what is the best practice for this" rather then the "what do you think about my solution" although I agree that there is an overlap. If other people think this as well I will post my question over there. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I'd personally go for composition.   It really is not that hard to do -> `function FormField(props) { return <SomeJSX..../>; }`  eg. In your example, I would just create a local one called `<FormField field="xyz"/>`..  Doing this way pay's in the long run.